# Check whether an item in a list exist in another list or not python

Tags: python

There are 2 list

```
a= [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
```

Now I want to check whether an element from `a` exist in `b` or not in python **one-liner**.

I can use loop on `a` and then check if it exist in `b` or not. But I want something pythonic way (one-liner).

Comment: One liner does not always mean it is pythonic.

Comment: what about `any(a) in b`

Comment: Agree. But I know I can convert it to one-liner in python, rather than using loops.

Comment: @Vahidabdi - I tried `a= [1,2,3]
b = [5,5,3]

print any(a) in b` . It gives me false.

Comment: yep `any(a) returns True(1) or False(0)` which is not in b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bool(set(a)&set(b))` converts `a` and `b` into sets and then applies the [intersection operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) (`&`) on them. Then bool is applied on the resulting set, which returns `False` if the set is empty (no element is common), otherwise `True` (the set is non-empty and has the common element(s)).

Without using sets: `any(True for x in a if x in b)`. `any()` returns True if any one of the elements is true, otherwise False.

Comment: What does it do? Please explain.

Comment: @user1162512 Updated it; I saw your comment while I was adding info on it.

Comment: I want to fetch that element from `a` also which exist in `b`. How can I do that?

Comment: @user1162512 Simply remove `bool()` and the set of common elements will be returned; you can find out the number of elements using `len(the_set)`.

Comment: Any specific reason on why do I require `set`. I mean I can do `a and b` as well

Comment: @user1162512 The list operator doesn't support intersection and the `&` operator doesn't work with lists. `and` is actually a different operator which returns the element which is true, otherwise False.

Comment: I didnt got this statment `and returns the element which is true` means?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42023/discussion-between-ramchandra-apte-and-user1162512)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use sets. This is the way you can do it:

```
def check_element(a, b):
  return not set(a).isdisjoint(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len(set(a+b)) < len(set(a)) + len(set(b))
```