# How to find a perfect match from multiple elements in a list on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, exact-match

Env Python3.6.
Here's a list I want to match some sentence.
(It's a bit tricky to replace it in English so I'll go with Japanese as it is.)

```
INPUT:
match_list=['…', '‥', '...', 'かも', '多分']
text = 'も'
if any(text in m for m in match_list):
    print(text)

OUTPUT: 'も'
```

This output seems different from my point.
It actually reacts to one of elements in the list: 'かも'
But what I want to know is if the text completely matches any one of the list, not partially.
Is there any better way to work it out? Thanks.

Comment: `if any(text == m for m in match_list):`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object in list that has attribute equal to some value (that meets any condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125467/find-object-in-list-that-has-attribute-equal-to-some-value-that-meets-any-condi) or [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/how-to-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list) or [Check whether an item in a list exist in another list or not python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238281/check-whether-an-item-in-a-list-exist-in-another-list-or-not-python)

Comment: Can you have more than one exact matches in the list @user9191983

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew youre very quick! thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad I could help, please close the question as a duplicate, it is surely a dupe of [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287) or [Check whether an item in a list exist in another list or not python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238281)

Comment: Check if my answer below helps you @user9191983 :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for equality for checking if the text exactly matches an element in the list, instead of the membership operator `in` which checks if the text is a substring of an element in list

```
match_list=['…', '‥', '...', 'かも', '多分', 'も']

text = 'も'
#Match exact string via equality
if any(text == m for m in match_list):
    print(text)
```

The output will be

```
も
```